# Is firing order sufficient to tell if a crankshaft is cross-plane or flat-plane?

Tags: diagnostics, crankshaft, firing-order, cross-plane, flat-plane

If I know the order in which the cylinders on a V-engine fire, can I know for sure whether the engine has a cross-plane or flat-plane crankshaft?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the firing order alternates from one bank to the other it could be (and probably is) a flat plane engine. If the firing order has any two cylinders on the same bank fire in succession, it cannot be a flat plane engine.

Comment: Go for it! I love a lively debate!  A flat plane must fire one bank then the other in order to keep it firing like two 4 cylinder banks. To keep it firing in a balanced manner. Could an engine be built to work differently? Yes, but it would have to fire two cylinders on the same bank simultaneously, which would not make for a smooth running engine at all. Not to mention quite a bumpy power transfer!! Let me know your thoughts. :-)